# Inno Setup: How to expand preprocessor variable in #error directive message

Tags: inno-setup, preprocessor

I have an Inno Setup script which looks for a file as a preprocessor step:

```
#define a_path GetEnv("INSTALLER_FILES")
#define install_file FindFirst(a_path + "\pattern*.*")
```

When the `install_file` is not found, I would like to emit an error:

```
#if install_file == 0
    #error No installer found at {#a_path}
#endif
```

But the ISPP only writes the literal source line on compilation:

> script.iss: [ISPP] No installer found at {#a_path}

Is it possible to expand a preprocessor variable in the `#error` directive?

Answer (score 5):

The argument of the [`#error` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=error) cannot contain variables.

But you can use the [`#pragma error` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=pragma) instead:

```
#pragma error "No installer found at " + a_path
```